# STS export war ignoring maven packagingExcludes

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

I've spent several hours trying out variations of `<packagingExcludes>` to exclude files from a war file without any success.  I've looked at the Maven documentation and dozens of SO posts so I must be missing something fundamental.

My first question is when I right-click the project and select Export | Web | WAR file shouldn't that execute the maven-war-plugin in the project's POM?  If not, then how do I create the war?  Command line?  Run As | m2 build?

Assuming the Export is executing the maven-war-plugin, then here's the section from my pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                ...
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <packagingExcludes>
                    WEB-INF/classes/profile.properties
                </packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>                
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have tried multiple variations on `WEB-INF/classes/profile.properties` and the file still ends up in the .war file when I examine it with 7-zip.  The file is in my src/main/resources directory and ends up in WEB-INF/classes in the war file.  Any help would be greatly appreciated - this is driving me nuts.

Comment: No it shouldn't, your assumption is wrong... That uses the plain export function from Eclipse not maven. If you want maven then launch maven using m2.

Comment: Thanks.  I had a feeling that's what was happening.  Appreciate your quick response.